# Grid layout spanning by rows and columns

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

How to 'span' a column equivalent to two columns in the first row and then for the second row, one column each as show in the screenshot (I've two columns in the second row)

**CSS**

```css
main section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    justify-items: stretch;
}

#product {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}

#detail {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
}

#customer {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<section>
    <div id="product"></div>
    <div id="detail"></div>
    <div id="customer"></div>
</section>
```

---

Screenshot from https://learncssgrid.com/ - the difference here is that I have two columns in the second row.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `span 2` to the first element:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  justify-items: stretch;
}

#product {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

section>* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="product"></div>
  <div id="detail"></div>
  <div id="customer"></div>
</section>
```